# IIS:\\AppPools appears to be empty when used from inside application pool

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, hangfire

I am trying to run a PowerShell script to set some properties on an IIS application pool. The script works fine when I run it from the PowerShell application. However, it does not work when running from inside an IIS application pool.

The script looks as follows:

```
import-module webadministration

$WebSiteName = "MyWebsite"
$WebSiteFullName = "IIS:\Sites\" + $WebSiteName
$ApplicationPool = Get-Item $WebSiteFullName | Select-Object applicationPool
$ApplicationPoolFullName = "IIS:\AppPools\" + $ApplicationPool.applicationPool

Add-WebConfiguration -filter '/system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders' -value (@{name="ApplicationPreload";type="MyApplication.ApplicationPreload, MyApplication"})

set-itemproperty $WebSiteFullName -name applicationDefaults.serviceAutoStartEnabled -value True
set-itemproperty $WebSiteFullName -name applicationDefaults.serviceAutoStartProvider -value 'ApplicationPreload'

set-itemproperty $ApplicationPoolFullName -name autoStart -value True
set-itemproperty $ApplicationPoolFullName -name startMode -value 1 # 1 = AlwaysRunning
```

Its purpose is to make an ASP.NET application using Hangfire always running, as described here: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

The script runs fine when run in the PowerShell application.

However, when it from the ASP.NET application using `System.Management.Automation`, the last two lines fail. The error message is:

```
Cannot find path 'IIS:\\AppPools\\fwsetupsite' because it does not exist.
```

As a test, I added a line

```
dir IIS:\AppPools > c:\apppools.txt
```

which produces an empty file `c:\apppools.txt` if run from the ASP.NET application, but correctly dumps the names of all application pools into the file when run from the PowerShell application. So it seems that `IIS:\\AppPools` is empty.

The C# code which runs the script from within the ASP.NET application looks as follows:

```
using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    string script = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
    shell.AddScript(script);
    shell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: There is an unanswered question with a slightly similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653205/powershell-set-itemproperty-not-working-when-script-running-from-c-sharp-webapp

Comment: The ASP.NET application runs as a 64-bit process, and so does the PowerShell script. I have confirmed this by adding test code: `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess > c:\bitness.txt`. Also, while attempting to run the script in 32-bit PowerShell does fail, it fails with different error message, so bitness of the PowerShell script is likely not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that making the modifications to the application pool in a background job solves the problem:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($ApplicationPoolFullName)

    import-module webadministration

    # Enable auto start and always running on application pool
    set-itemproperty $ApplicationPoolFullName -name autoStart -value True
    set-itemproperty $ApplicationPoolFullName -name startMode -value 1 # 1 = AlwaysRunning, 0 = OnDemand
} -ArgumentList $ApplicationPoolFullName

Wait-Job $job | Out-Null

if ($job.State -eq 'Failed') {
    exit 1
}
```

I am still curious about why it doesn't work when doing it directly in the main script, though.

Comment: this doesnt work for me. Just fails in the background instead.